# SharePoint 2010 workflows suddenly does not work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I've been having this issue and been looking for a solution to no avail.

Situation A:
We have a SharePoint 2010 site which contains a list that has a SharePoint Designer workflow. Now everything seems to be working fine, the workflow runs upon item creation and so on, then after quite some time with no one actually editing anything, the workflow just stopped working, no status in the workflow column as well, just suddenly no workflow activities happening in that list, anyone encountered this/knows a solution for this?

Situation B:
We have a SharePoint 2010 site, same as above, we have a list that has a SharePoint designer workflow attached to it. Now this workflow intermittently stops, just suddenly doesn't work upon item creation, no status in workflow columns as well. What happens is that we tried to edit the item and save it again multiple times before it runs. Any idea what's happening?

EDIT: As per checking, I can manually start the workflow.

Comment: If you go to the list can you still see the workflow, can you start in manually?

Comment: will try this one and let you know, but if ever, this is not a good solution for our end though.

Comment: Does the workflow fully work and complete when manually started? What does the workflow do? I'm wondering if whatever the workflow does is throwing an error and isn't being logged, Have you checked through the ULS logs?

Comment: nothing i see in the ULS logs sadly, I made a workflow that only places a value in a column, shouldn't really have any wrong stuff in the workflow. and yep, the workflow fully works when manually started.

Comment: It's not something to do with permissions is it? Seems very odd that it would just stop.Have you tried redeploying the workflow via designer? Does this happen for all users?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, yes, I've tried re-saving and redeploying to no avail. This is also the first time I've encountered this (serious) issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in any of the server logs?

Comment: Nope, didn't see any errors..

Comment: Is the Windows SharePoint Services Timer V4 service (SPTimerV4) running? If it is try restarting it.

Comment: @aquila, done to no avail.

Comment: Are the workflows being triggered on item edit? If so this may be causing recursion and this is not allowed, have a look through the ULS logs for this.

Comment: Hi Aquila, nope, not being triggered on edit as well, there are (random) times it is being triggered on item creation, and on item edit (wherein both satisfies the workflow conditions at all times)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Workflow Settings can revert to "No New Instances" when you deploy changes to a workflow. You might want to check that.

Otherwise, it doesn't sound like you have a DelayActivity, but it's historically been a place where workflows can hang because of a bug worked around in this blog:
http://the-simple-programmer.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepoint-workflow-delay-activity.html

You basically have to run:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-workflow -pv "Every 5 minutes between 0 and 59" -url http://yoursite
```

Comment: sadly this seems unjustifiable.. first we don't have a delayed workflow running in that subsite.. ever. It was a new subsite created. Also, we can't just run scripts in the server, since this is in a production environment and we cannot replicate the issue in the dev environment where we can test this. And lastly, if it's getting confused, why are there times when it runs and sometimes not.

Comment: i'll be awarding you the bounty though this didn't really work, you've given the best answer so far :)

Comment: Sorry it didn't fix the problem! Those were the best things I could think of to try.

Answer (score 0):

Check your workflow history list. you may get clear picture of what stoping your workflow.

Comment: nope, it doesn't even show it running at times (totally no status from the workflow column in the list)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is the reason, but is there a chance that somebody has disabled the Workflows features from the Site settings

Comment: sorry for the late response, but nope, checked that feature as well in the site collection level but it is activated.